# Use material assigned to curve in geometry nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I have a curves object made up of multiple disconnected curves.
I have two material slots and assigned one of the two materials to each of these curves.

I generate a mesh from the curves via geometry nodes.
It's hair. I want to give different color to some strands.

The generated mesh doesn't have any material. It comes out as white. How could I fix that? How could I use the material assigned to each curve for the material of the generated mesh?

The geometry nodes:

[image: geometry nodes for hair]

Comment: I feel like the solution is something like "Capture attribute" for the curve but capture the material somehow, then "Set Material" that on the generated mesh?

Comment: Short answer: You cannot read the material currently assigned to a curve in Geometry Nodes. The only way is to explicitly specify a material that you can apply to the mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate each curve in its own object, you can just use `Set Material` or `Set Material Index` on the `Curve to Mesh` result directly.

If you are generating multiple meshes based on 1 curve in the same geometry node, I've gotten the following to work with Blender 3.4.1

TL;DR: assign a dummy `Capture Attribute` boolean node ticked to true and use it as the selection input to `Set Material` on the `Curve to Mesh` result

Nodes:

[image: Nodes]

Result:

[image: Result]